# toggle state doesn't change when another is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, the icon needs to be clicked in order to change state. I'm trying to have the state change when another is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordian-content').hide();
  $('.accordian-title').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').toggleClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
    $('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well or JSFiddle even better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u8dbpnnf/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordian-content').hide();
  $('.accordian-title').click(function() {
  const flag = $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').hasClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
   $('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
    $('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
    if(!flag) {
    $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').addClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
    } else {
     $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your effort.The icon now changes when another title is clicked but does not change when the same title is clicked (revert to previous state)

Comment: @CDavies  Please check out this. Now it will work properly.